# trying to iterate through the first object and adding the current item into another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For every object in trackInfo array of objects I would like to add an additional object by iterating through features array. How would I do this?

I have already tried -

```
let trackInfo = [ // 1st array of objects getting from API
                 {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id},
                 {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id}, 
                 {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id}] 

let features = [ // 2nd array of objects getting from API
                 {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id},
                 {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id}, 
                 {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id}] 

          
                     trackInfo.forEach((object) => {
                        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                           object.analysis = features[i]
                        }
                     })
                  })
```

However, this only results in the last object from features array being added to all the track info objects. I want the whole first object of features to be added with the key "analysis" to be the first item/object in trackInfo and so on. I hope this isn't confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` to loop through `trackInfo` and add the `analysis` object to each array element:

```js
let trackInfo = [ // 1st array of objects getting from API
                 {name: 'name1', id: 1},
                 {name: 'name2', id: 2}, 
                 {name: 'name3', id: 3}] 

let features = [ // 2nd array of objects getting from API
                 {loud: 'track1', beat: 'b1'},
                 {loud: 'track2', beat: 'b2'}, 
                 {loud: 'track3', beat: 'b3'}] 

trackInfo = trackInfo.map((obj,idx) => {
  obj['analysis'] = features[idx] 
  return obj
})
console.log(trackInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick using [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/shift) like this :

```js
let trackInfo = [ // 1st array of objects getting from API
  {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id},
  {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id},
  {name: item.track.name, id: item.track.id}
 ]

let features = [ // 2nd array of objects getting from API
  {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id},
  {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id},
  {loud: item.track.name, beat: item.track.id}
]

trackInfo.forEach((object) => {
  object.analysis = features.shift();
})
```